# Can someone explain this output?

Tags: c, scanf, undefined-behavior

I was going through some program when i came across this.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void main()
{
char z;
do
{
    printf("1st line\n");
    printf("2nd line\n");
            scanf("%c",&z);

    switch(z)
    {
        case 'a':printf("this is case a\n");
            break;
        case 'b':printf("this is case b\n");
            break;
        case 'c':printf("Exit\n");
            return;
            break;
        default:
            printf("this is default\n");
            break;
    }
}while(1);
```

}

1st time i give an input, the output is proper. But after the first input is given and the loop starts for the second time, scanf statement isn't executed at all. The printf statements get executed though and also the default case.

> 1st line
>   2nd line
>   b
>   this is case b
>   1st line
>   2nd line
>   this is default
>   1st line
>   2nd line

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you entered `b` for the first `scanf` call, you also hit [enter](/questions/tagged/enter). When `scanf("%c", &z)` processed this input, it left the newline character in the input stream.

The second set of output is due to the `scanf` reading the newline character that followed `b`. Since `\n` is neither `a`, nor `b`, nor `c`, it hits the default case.

You can fix the behavior to be more like what you expect by modifying your `scanf` string:

```
scanf(" %c", &z);
```

Note the space character before the `%c`. This will cause `scanf` to skip whitespace characters (including the newline) before processing the input.

Answer (score 4):

1. `int main()`.
2. No undefined behavior here. It's just that `scanf()` doesn't work how you think it does. `%c` consumes a character. **A** character. **One.** And it doesn't consume the newline that's left in the buffer of `stdin` after you hit Enter. (So "the second scanf isn't executed" is not true - it's executed and it processes whatever is left for it.) Now, the newline character isn't either one of a, b or c, so the `switch` statement continues execution at the `default:` label.

---

If you want to read a character from the standard input, a reliable way is:

```
char buf[LINE_MAX];
fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin);
switch (buf[0]) {
    // etc.
}
```

alternative:

```
int c = fgetc(stdin);
while (fgetc(stdin) == '\n')
    ;
```

Don't use `scanf()`. (At least not until you understand what it does.) It's evil.

Comment: +1, I agree that `scanf()` should generally be avoided.

Comment: @H2CO3, I tested this sample with Eclipse and gcc, and it behaves as the OP expected. Does this mean that eclipse doesn't put the `\n` in the stream? I also thought that the return key would be the problem, so I was surprised that it works.

Comment: When running it on the console, it is as you described, so it seems that Eclipse is indeed swallowing the `\n` itself.

Comment: @Devolus I think in this case it does. (Thanks for giving me another reason to hate IDEs, I collect those!)

Answer (score 1):

No big problem, you just ignore to handle the '\n' input after each character, you may do it this way:

```
scanf("%c\n",&z);
```

So that you can avoid handling '\n'.